# Check html page is open or not., if open don't reopen or reload stop executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    if (i<=5)
{
 myWindow = window.open("help.html", "myWindow");
}
```

here it will check the input if value is 5 it will open help.html, if value is 4,3,2,1 will open or reload each time with help.html., what i need is one time it should open that html file and if values goes to 4,3,2,1 or any combination it should not again reload or open another window, same help.html page. instead it should check whether help.html is open or not if open it should stop executing., if close it can open help.html., Guide me..

```
    var windows = {};
$('a').click(function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    if(windows.hasOwnProperty(name) && !windows[name].closed ) 
    {
       windows[name].focus();   
    }
    else  
    {
       windows[name]=window.open (url,name,"status=1,width=300,height=300");
    }    
});
```

i found this example but how to combine with my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the snippet and working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m3qzujy2/)

```
    var i = 3, //hard-coded i vlaue here
    myWindow = {
        closed: true  //needed this property 
    };

    $('#btn').click(function () {

        if (i <= 5 && myWindow.closed) {
            myWindow = window.open("http://jsfiddle.net/");
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you give some live example i tried but my page still reloads

Comment: thanks ., but without click function i need, like in textbox like <input id="x" type="number" onkeyup="update('y')"> compare value execute automatically @venkat7668

Comment: i have shared my answer for your reference., by using it i solved the issue thanks for your support ., @venkat7668

Comment: You are welcome Mahesh, accept the answer if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var myWindow;
function openWin() {
if (!myWindow){
  myWindow = window.open("", "");
}
}

function closeWin() {
    if (myWindow) {
        myWindow.close();
    }
}

function checkWin() {
    msg = ""
    if (!myWindow) {
        msg = "was never opened";
    } else { 
        if (myWindow.closed) { 
            msg = "is closed";
        } else {
            msg = "is open";
        }
    
    } 
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = 
    "myWindow " + msg;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open myWindow</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close myWindow</button>
<button onclick="checkWin()">Is myWindow open?</button>

<br><br>
<div id="msg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

i utilized this example and solved the issue.,